# Get boolean value from Retrofit2 onResponse

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to make an asynchronous request to the server, which should return me true or false. But the problem is that the function first returns false, and only then the retrofit function is triggered. How can I get the value I need while maintaining the speed of program execution?
My code:

```
private static boolean find;
public boolean checkAccountByPhone(String phone){

    Log.d("dbHandler", "function started...");

    DbHandler.getApi().checkAccountByPhone(phone).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            Log.d("dbHandler", "data is: "+response.body().equals("true"));

            // return response.body().equals("true");

            Log.d("dbHandler", "sent!");

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("dbHandler", t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    Log.d("dbHandler", "returned: "+DbHandler.find);
    return DbHandler.find; // always false???
}
```

Comment: Return live data or use suspend function with retrofit service using coroutine.
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#0

Your call back are asyn and you cant put return statement there.

Comment: @Mundroid suspend function works only with kotlin?

Comment: @Mundroid I tried using coroutine functions, but they still fire after the return of the main function. are there any other solutions to the problem?

Comment: Why you returning value from function before getting it? Once you get value from server post it in live data and observe in UI (activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify logic in Java, this code is for reference to avoid callback.

```
 fun checkAccountByPhone(phone: String):String{
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response : Response<String> = try {
            DbHandler.getApi().checkAccountByPhone(phone)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.logException()
            null
        }

        //you can check response.body() here and can post either response.body() or DbHandler.find
        _yourLiveData.post(response.body() or DbHandler.find)


}
```